# C++ garbage collected compiler

Tags: c++, c++11, garbage-collection

Does anyone know of a good compiler for c++ that supports garbage collection. I know that they were considering it for c++11 but didn't implement it.

Comment: Who needs garbage collection with RAII in place?

Comment: Because if you download many c++ open source projects they are filled with memory leaks, people can't handle doing their own memory management

Comment: You can use `smart_pointers` from `boost`, makes life easier for managing pointers.

Comment: Actually c++11 already supports its own type of native smart pointers, called shared_pointer, I just asked the question because I am curious

Comment: @aaronman, Don't forget `std::unique_ptr`. That's the one you should be using by default.

Comment: @chris, I know of both of them, as I said I'm really just interested to know if there is a good garbage collected compiler for c++

Comment: What you are looking for is called managed C++. Visual Studio/.NET supports that. However, it's not standardized so I would not advice it unless you are certain you will be developing in MS for eternity. Smart pointers can give you pretty everything you need (I'm not sure why you are looking for garbage collected C++, the compiler will most likely not solve the 3rd party memory leaks you are mentioning).

Comment: MIhgt not be what you are looking for but take a look at Boehm's conservative GC, http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/. Can be added to existing code fairly easily, but more easily to C code than C++.

Comment: @gvd, if the whole project was made using a garbage collected compiler why wouldn't it stop the mem leaks

Comment: @aaronman GC in C++ is often opt-in, so just getting a compiler that supports it won't automatically fix memory issues. Afaik managed C++ isn't supported again, Microsoft have ditched it for C++/CX. This has a ref counted class "ref class", which will delete when it has no refs (so not GC), but this is more geared towards .NET interop, and has a whole host of other complexities.

Comment: c++ doesn't have gc as a part of language. using RAII in programming (smart pointers such as unique_ptr,shared_ptr,weak_ptr) you can achieve some gc behavior. It's only programmer driven not compiler driven.

Comment: One of C++'s strengths is its deterministic memory model. You can tell by looking at the code when the memory is going to be released.

Comment: @anthony-arnold: Too bad this place when the memory is going to be released almost always looks like this: `}`.

Comment: @Joker_vD You get used to the idea.

Comment: If you download a "C++ ***open source*** project [...] filled with memory leaks", fix it and submit a patch to the maintainer!

Comment: @chris: A GC brings 2 guarantees to the table: 1/ no leak, 2/ no dangling reference. Smart pointers help in getting no leak (if wielded correctly), however dangling references *still* are a plague.

Comment: @guysherman *C++/CX* doesn't really have much to do with *.NET* and isn't geared for *.NET* interop in any way. What you maybe meant was *C++/CLI*, the successor of *Managed C++* (and a garbage collected *.NET*-language, too). But in the end the whole discussion about *C++/CX* or *C++/CLI* or *Managed C++* is completely irrelevant anyway, since they're entirely different langauges from *C++*, which is the language the OP asked for and his supposedly leaking thrid party projects are in).

Comment: @ChristianRau you're right, C++/CX is not technically for .NET interop, it is for the "COM-based WinRT programming model", however to put it simply, the ultimate goal is for interop with managed code, ie .NET in the Microsoft world. Furthermore, if you read my comment properly, you will see that my reason for mentioning it was not as a suggested solution, but to point out that, contrary to one of the previous posts, C++/CLI (so called managed C++) is deprecated, and is clearly not an answer to the OP's question. Please read posts carefully before asserting that the poster is uninformed.

Comment: @guysherman *"Furthermore, if you read my comment properly, you will see that my reason for mentioning it was not as a suggested solution"* - Neither was my last sentence supposed to imply that. *"Please read posts carefully before asserting that the poster is uninformed."* - I'll leave my previous sentence (and the now hopefully clear implications of this sentence) as comment on that.

Comment: @ChristianRau Ok, I take your point. For the sake of clarity, I will re-state my original comment in a better way: C++/CLI, or "Managed C++" is not a "Garbage Collected C++", it is different, and also deprecated. It's successor, C++/CX, generates completely native code, but is really not intended for general C++ usage, it is specifically for interoperability with the rest of the Windows Runtime ecosystem, and is therefore, not an appropriate answer to the OP's question. I think we are in "violent agreement".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the most-often heard of approaches is to use Hans Boehm's GC, which can be plugged into C++. Of course, an alternative is to use smart pointers that keep track of the use of objects.

For everybody who upvoted the "who needs this" comment, the answer is that it can be more expensive:

- Imagine that you fork() your program and now start adjusting refcounters in objects that remain constant otherwise. This will cause performance overhead because it means that the OS can't share the memory between the two processes, i.e. it breaks copy-on-write. In some cases, it can mean that the OS has to swap in memory only to copy and adjust reference counters.
- Another example is something like the suggested `boost::shared_ptr`. Each of these has an additional allocation as overhead in order to store the reference counter, weak reference counter and deleter. This doesn't come for free either. Further, an instance thereof has twice the size of a pointer.
- Then, if you use a normal size_t for the refcounter and built-in increment/decrement, your code isn't multithreading safe. However, if you use atomic integers, incrementing and decrementing takes much more time to flush caches and because it disallows reordering. Remember, every time you copy such a pointer, you have to increment the reference counter. Every time one instance is destroyed, you have to decrement the counter again. Maintaining a reference count can accumulate to much higher overhead that using a mark-and-sweep GC to count references now and then.
- Lastly, refcounted pointers need the programmer to actively consider the possibility of cycles. GCs can detect and break cycles automatically.

If you keep the above in mind, a GC is an alternative. It does have disadvantages, like non-deterministic cleanup, but Java and C# show that you can live with this and there is nothing that keeps you from programming it yourself in those places where you really need it.

Comment: 2nd bullet: `std::make_shared` avoids the additional allocation, it coalesces the two. This improves locality of reference and reduces fragmentation. This also reduces the penalty of cache flushes, as the object is often flushed alongside its count. (3rd bullet). Of course, if you use `fork`, this sharing amplifies the COW problem.

Comment: @MSalters: Not to mention that the C++ Standard discourages COW (see how they changed `std::basic_string`s requirements...)

Comment: @MFH: That's a completely different kind of COW. It has to copy on a _possible_ write, i.e. after calling the non-const `operator[]`, whereas the page copy happens only on a physical write, blocks only the writing thread, and is optimally (page) aligned.

Comment: Actually, if you know a set of objects will be constant after the `fork`, you can create your own `make_shared_fork<T>` that keeps all counter in one memory pool and all constant objects in another. That way, the first COW will copy _all_ counters and only the counters.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you can get around fine using RAII and smart pointers (such as `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr` in C++11).

However, if you need garbage collection, look into Boehm's garbage collector. You could overload `operator new` as following.

```
enum GCPlacement {
    NoGC,
    GC,
};

void* operator new(size_t size, GCPlacement gcp) {
    void* toReturn;

    if (gcp == GC) toReturn = GC_MALLOC(size);
    else toReturn = GC_MALLOC_UNCOLLECTABLE(size);

    if (!toReturn) throw std::bad_alloc();
    else return toReturn;
}

void operator delete(void* p, GCPlacement) {
    GC_FREE(p);
}
```

Now, you can allocate garbage collected memory as following:

```
Object* o = new (GC) Object();
```

If you want, you can also derive certain classes from the `gc` class provided by boehmgc to indicate these should always be allocated using garbage collection.

C++/CLI is another solution, but be advised that it technically is not C++ (it is an extension of a partial implementation of C++) and it ties you to the Microsoft/.NET platform -- essentially, it's just C# with a C++ syntax.